# What would be considered the number of elements in a boolean satisfiability problem?

Tags: algorithm, np, np-complete

Another way to put this question is, if a boolean satisfiability solution had an efficiency of O(2^n), what would be considered n?

It seems like it could be the number of variables in the expression, or the number of clauses in the expression, or some third option I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Out of context it's impossible to say.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat do you mean that different solutions to this problem consider different things to be the number of elements?

Comment: If we're doing algorithms, then I think n = number of variables and m = number of clauses would be expected. If we're doing complexity, then we could have something like n being the number of bits or words to specify the input (depending on the machine model).